# Angular 4, Make ng lint error fatal

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Angular CLI has a built in linter, running `ng lint` will lint my code base and report any errors. It can even fix some automatically.

Is there a way I can make linter errors fatal whilst runnning the site with `ng serve`? i.e I want to display an error message on the front page of the site if any code isn't properly linted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with today's tools.

What you can do is get a `tslint` extension in your favourite editor. This will show the errors in the editor. For VS Code, just searching for `tslint` will show the extension directly.

You can also make it part of an NPM script. For example, in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "ng lint && ng build"
}
```

This is still not interactive, but you can a version of it that developers are required to run before pushing code, and your CI build tool runs as well.

For interactive experience, a code editor extension is as close as this gets. In VS Code the tslint errors show in the file itself, and in the errors panel as well, which works nicely for the developers I work with.

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. Was thinking of putting `ng lint` in a post commit git hook. Then at least the changes can't be committed.